# How to calculate the offset based on xy coordinates to read from numpy.memmap?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, offset

I have created the large `numpy array` using `numpy.memmap` like below.

```
import numpy as np
memmapData = np.memmap('test.memmap', dtype='uint8', mode='w+', shape=(10000, 10000, 3))
```

Now how to read the array based on some XY coordinates. After reading, I need to draw a rectangle.

(i.e) X1=0,Y1=1000 X2=X1+500,Y2=Y1+500. So now how can I read the numpy array from `test.memmap` by above coordinates. In this how do I need to use numpy.memmap attribute `offset` .

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use the `offset`?  Can't you just index it like a regular array?

```
In [221]: memmapData = np.memmap('test.memmap', dtype='uint8', mode='w+', shape=
     ...: (10, 10, 3))

In [222]: memmapData[...]=np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)[:,:,None]

In [223]: memmapData[0,5,:]
Out[223]: memmap([5, 5, 5], dtype=uint8)

In [224]: memmapData[0,5:,:]
Out[224]: 
memmap([[5, 5, 5],
       [6, 6, 6],
       [7, 7, 7],
       [8, 8, 8],
       [9, 9, 9]], dtype=uint8)
```

`offset` is a parameter you can supply when creating the map.  It's fixed.  You don't fiddle with it to access elements.

Comment: @ hpaulj can you explain me your code little bit briefly?